# Excel CONCATENATE function produces error when referencing a worksheet with space in name

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013

In Microsoft Office Excel 2013 on a Windows 8.1 PC, I get an error message, *#NAME?*, when trying to do the following:

```
=CONCATENATE('Calculation Sheet'!D, "- Customer Sales")
```

Doing the same with an ampersand produces the expected output:

```
='Calculation Sheet'!D3&" - Customer Sales"
```

Can anyone help me understand this? Thanks!

Comment: Is the missing row on the first attempt just a typo into this question?  Or are you really missing the 3 on that attempt?

Comment: How embarrassing! Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the full address of the cell.  use:

=CONCATENATE('Calculation Sheet'!D3, "- Customer Sales")

rather than:

=CONCATENATE('Calculation Sheet'!D, "- Customer Sales")

Comment: You are entirely correct. And to think I proofread my post several times before submitting... Thanks for your help!